# How to create a view from referenced nodes

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I am having a problem with Drupal 7 Views relationships/contextual filters.

Let me explain it with an example.
I want to make a photo album.

I'm having a content type 'cat'.
This content type has some fields like name, weight, etc.

I'm having a second content type 'photos'.
This content type has an image field and a field named 'cats'.
The field 'cats' is an entity reference to one or more nodes of type 'cat'.
(There can be multiple cats on one picture).

On the node view of type 'cat' I want to show a views block with all photos that reference the current node.

And this is where I'm stuck.

I tried a multitude of combinations of relationships and contextual filters.
Mostly my view didn't bring up any photos or photos not referencing the nodes.

It would be a great help for me if someone could explain me how to construct my view.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to select your relationship to be:

```
Content-<cat-reference-field-name> - reverse
```

There should be an option like that in your '**Relationships**'.  Just make sure you select the cat field and the '**- reverse**' option.

[image]

Second, you need to add a 'Contextual filter'.  Set that to be 'Content: cat-field', and set the default value to be '**Content ID from URL**'.  Up at the top, make sure to select the already created relationship from the drop down list:

[image]

Finally - on the fields of your image that you want to appear in the 'Fields' section, but *select the created relationship* for those as well (just like you did for the Contextual filter)!

Save, and if you've placed this block on a cat page, it should work.  Let us know if it does!

Comment: Hi Boriana, thank you for helping, but I can't seem to find a 'reverse option'. Do I have to install an additional module for that?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe entity reference and node reference have different integrations with views.  The fields I was testing with (that I have on my Drupal site) are node references, not entity references, and I've edited my response above to show you how they appear on the 'Relationship' screen.  Perhaps you need to change the type of your fields to accommodate the views integration you expect to have?

Comment: Hi Boriana, thank you for helping again. It looks like entity reference doesn't has the 'reverse' option implemented the same way as node reference. Browsing the internet I finally found the solution on this [page](http://drupal.org/node/1724396#comment-6406274).